# How to remove monaca flash screen from monaca android build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui, monaca

I created android app. but whenever it loading it shows default monaca flash screen. I want to customize in my way. how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Monaca default splash screen, you need to go to `Config -> Android App Settings`. You will see that there is a section called `Splash files`, like this:

[image]

Just edit the files for the various resolutions and reload/build again the app.